# Find the number of substrings of this string that start and end with different characters

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, substring

Find the number of substrings of this string that start and end with different characters.
If the same substring appears multiple times in S, it is to be counted multiple times.

What approach should i follow. My solution is not optimised

Comment: `My solution is not optimised` - nevertheless, it is worth to describe it

Comment: Do not tag this as `dsa`.  The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.

Answer (score 2):

There are `P=n*(n+1)/2` possible substrings of the string with length `n` (including 1-length ones)

Find counts for every distinct character in the string.

```
banana => {'b':1; 'a':3; 'n':2}
```

If some char `c` occurs `k` times,  there are `k*(k+1)/2` substrings that  start and end with this character `c` (including 1-length ones again!) - so we must subtract this quantity from overall `P`.
Repeat for other chars.

```
21 - 1 -6 - 3 = 11
```

If substring length should be >=2, then we have to use  `P=n*(n-1)/2` and `k*(k-1)/2` formulas

```
15  -0 -3 -1 = 11
```

Surprisingly, result is the same ;)

Comment: @AkashAnand Is my answer still unclear?